# Google Cloud SQL: Can I change machine type with zero downtime on my database clients?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to update the machine type of my Google Cloud instance, but this takes several minutes to update (second generation instance). The instance will be unavailable until the instance has restarted. Because of this downtime, we have to update the machine type at night time, so our visitors are the least troubled by this update.

Is there a workflow how we can minimise this downtime to zero or maybe a few seconds? I already thought about possible solutions like adding a temporary failover or maybe make use of read replica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the support of Google Cloud about this question and they told me that Cloud SQL isn't build to perform this change without downtime. If I want to be able to make these changes, I should look at Cloud Spanner which is a horizontal scalable SQL solution provided by Google.